# NSDateFormatter and date conversion not working

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, ios-simulator

I am developing an app for the iPhone where I need to convert an date from an XML feed into just a HH:MM format.

I have the following method that doesn't work and I have no clue what I am doing wrong.

As an example, the timeToConvert string would be: "**Mon, 01 Feb 2010 21:55:00 +0100**" (without the quotes)

The method works when the region is set to US (I get back the correct date), but not when I change the region (in Settings->General->International) to Spain, or other regions (in that case I get back nil).

```
- (id)timeConvertToHHMM:(NSString *)timeToConvert {

    NSString *newPubDate = timeToConvert;
    //Let's remove any rubbish from the code
    newPubDate = [newPubDate stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    //create formatter and format to convert the XML string to an NSDate
    NSDateFormatter *originalDateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [originalDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMM yyyy H:mm:ss z"];
    //run the string through the formatter
    NSDate *formattedDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    formattedDate = [originalDateFormatter dateFromString:newPubDate];
    //Let's now create another formatter to take the NSDate and convert format it to Hours and minutes
    NSDateFormatter *newDateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [newDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"]; // 24H clock set
    // And let's convert it back to a readable string
    NSString *calcHHMM = [newDateFormatter stringFromDate:formattedDate];
    NSLog(@"CalcHHMM: %@", calcHHMM);
    return calcHHMM;  
}
```

Any hint on why this is not working, and just returning NULL will be more than welcome.

Comment: Do you get an error or is it returning the wrong hours?

Comment: Just returns NULL... looks like all works up till

formattedDate = [originalDateFormatter dateFromString:newPubDate];

Comment: The code works for me except it returns the time converted to my local time zone.  What is the value of formattedDate when you pass it the example string?

Comment: Ok, for some reason, it's not able to parse the string using the format you supplied in originalDateFormatter.  Don't know why it works for me but you may have to do a setLocale on your formatter?  Also, when you remove the "z" at the end of the format, it will return the hours as is without converting to local time.

Comment: Looks like the REGION in settings have to do with it. 

When I set it to United States, it works, but if I set it to Spain (for example) it stops working and just returns NULL...

I tried to add: [originalDateFormatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"es_ES"] autorelease]]; but doesn't work...

Comment: @DyingCactus the solution seems to be what you posted... I've now made originalDateFormatter NSDateFormatter as: [originalDateFormatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] autorelease]];  <-- It works now, so if you submit the solution I'll gladly mark it as solved. Thank you for your help

Comment: Also, when you declare formattedDate, you're alloc/init'ing an NSDate instance, and then throwing it away in the next line when you call dateFromString, so you have a memory leak.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Problem appears to be your region setting is not "en-US" so the date formatter doesn't parse the string using the en-US format supplied.  Although there may be a more elegant, general solution, doing a setLocale on originalDateFormatter to en_US can be used as a workaround to solve the problem.

As you've already tried in your code:

```
[originalDateFormatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] autorelease]];
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue. My problem was that my initial date string had a single millisecond character:

Example: `2011-02-06 08:13:22:1`

and was being parsed with this format :`[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];`

The iPhone simulator was forgiving and successfully parsed the date with the milliseconds, however when building to my iphone it did not.
Changing the formatter to: `[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"];` solved the problem.